# Meteor code must always run within a fiber when deploy in meteor server

Tags: mongodb, deployment, meteor, meteorite, node-fibers

I kept having this error when i deploy my app onto meteor cloud server.

> Meteor code must always run within a Fiber
>       at _.extend.get (app/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:14:13)
>       at _.extend.apply (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1268:57)
>       at _.extend.call (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1229:17)
>       at Meteor.startup.Meteor.methods.streamTwit (app/server/server.js:50:24)

however, I have already wrapped within Fibers

```
streamTwit: function (twit){
    var userid = '1527228696';
    twit.stream(
    'statuses/filter',
    { follow: userid},
      function(stream) {
          stream.on('data', function(tweet) {

          Fiber(function(){
            if(tweet.user.id_str === userid)
            {
              Meteor.call('addQn', tweet);
            }
          }).run();
              console.log(tweet);
              console.log('---------------------------------------------------------');
              console.log(tweet.user.screen_name);
              console.log(tweet.user.name);
              console.log(tweet.text);
          });
        }
      );
    }
```

I don't know what's the reason but someone suggested that i should wrap it with Meteor.bindEnvironment instead. Hence, I did this:

```
streamTwit: function (twit){
    this.unblock(); // this doesn't seem to work
    console.log('... ... trackTweets');
    var _this = this;
    var userid = '1527228696';
    twit.stream(
    'statuses/filter',
    { follow: userid},
      function(stream) {
          stream.on('data', function(tweet) {

           Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
            if(tweet.user.id_str === userid)
            {
              Meteor.call('addQn', tweet);
            }
           }, function(e) {
             Meteor._debug("Exception from connection close callback:", e);
         });
              console.log(tweet);
              console.log('---------------------------------------------------------');
              console.log(tweet.user.screen_name);
              console.log(tweet.user.name);
              console.log(tweet.text);
          });
        }
      );
    }
```

//add question method

```
addQn:function(tweet){
      questionDB.insert({'tweet': tweet, 'date': new Date()});
    }
```

but now it doesn't even work. I realise that this only happened when I tried to insert some data into mongodb. 
May I know what is the problem with my code? Thanks!
All these codes were written in app/server/server.js

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use `Meteor.call` on the server side. That is for client-side code only. Just call `addQn` directly or better yet, inline it since it's just one line of code.

Comment: Hi, if I inline it. it will show Meteor code must run within a Fiber as well